# Headset powerlocus bluetooth microphone xubuntu 20.04

Tags: microphone, headset

I have a bluetooth headset but when I connect it to the computer the microphone doesn't work. It seems that it is not recognize as input device but just as output so the only thing that works is the audio.
Does anyone has any suggestion to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It seens to be a similar problem that I had. I was trying to use microphone with A2DP protocol which is not a bidirectional profile. So it will not get bi-directional audio.

Take a look on this [answer.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376095/bluetooth-microphone-does-not-work-in-ubuntu-20-04)