# bluetooth microphone does not work in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth, microphone

I have ubuntu 20.04, I can connect different bluetooth headphones, the audio works. But not the microphone.

Internet solutions are based on editing the `alsa-base.conf` file based on the audio driver.
But I can't find the settings for my pc

```
cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Nvidia GPU 9e HDMI/DP
Codec: Realtek ALCS1200A
```

Answer (score 2):

It seens to be a similar problem that I had. I was trying to use microphone with A2DP protocol which is not a bidirectional profile. So it will not get bi-directional audio.

In order to use the microphone you can change the A2DP profile to HSP/HFP profile.

If you can't do this for some reason, I recommend that you follow these steps (it works even if your bluetooth device is not the same).

The solution (elaborated by Atishya Gupta) is based on substitution of the sound server PulseAudio with Pipewire, which has support for most of the bluetooth profiles (HSP, HFP, A2DP etc). These are the steps to replace Pulseaudio with Pipewire :

1. We will use a PPA for adding Pipewire to Ubuntu 20.04, which is maintained regularly:

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream`
2. To update the PPA packages in your system do:

   `sudo apt-get update`
3. Install the package

   `sudo apt-get install pipewire`
4. If the following error appears "*Bluetooth headset won’t connect after installing pipewire*", install the dependency by:

   `sudo apt-get install libspa-0.2-bluetooth`
5. Now, To install the client libraries.

   `sudo apt install pipewire-audio-client-libraries`
6. Reload the Daemon

   `systemctl --user daemon-reload`
7. Disable Pulseaudio

   `systemctl --user --now disable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket`
8. Enable Pipewire

   `systemctl --user --now enable pipewire pipewire-pulse`
9. You also need to "mask" the Pulseaudio and after a new update, you also need to enable pipewire-media-session-service

   `systemctl --user mask pulseaudio`

   `systemctl --user --now enable pipewire-media-session.service`

Finally, you can ensure that Pipewire is now running through:

`pactl info`

Which must throw something like this:

`[..] PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.49)`

Comment: Hello. Please do not use links in an answer. What about later when the link does not work? Include the important info in the body of the answer.

Comment: Done that. Thanks @David